# Line instead of box in facet_wrap()

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to clean a `ggplot` with facets so that instead of the typical box around the facet label I can show a simple line (equivalent to the bottom line of the ).

The following code gets me almost all the way, but different from the desired output.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
 geom_point() +
 facet_wrap(~cyl) +
 theme_classic() +
 theme(strip.background = element_blank())
```

Desired output (edited manually). Ideally the length of the line would be slightly shorter than the `panel.background` (so that it doesn't touch the `y` axis)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe using annotate + segment

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(~cyl,) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(strip.background = element_rect(color = "white"),
          strip.placement = "inside",
          strip.text = element_text(vjust = -1)) + 
    annotate("segment",x = 10,xend = 34,y = 375,yend = 375, size = 0.5,) + 
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 360), clip="off")
```

[image]

Comment: This is actually pretty good. The one thing is that using annotate will always make it appear within the x or y axis, could we adapt it to be shown outside it (like the bottom line of the facets or even a bit higher) ?

Comment: You can combine it with coord_cartesian and clip="off". Will edit my response

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you want, but close...

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
theme_bw() +
theme(
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  strip.background = element_blank(),
  panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black")
)+
geom_point() +
facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

[image]

Comment: yes, been here, thought about it but not quite the style I'm looking for